# Smartgwt ListGrid Group order

Tags: sorting, smartgwt

I have a ListGrid with 3 columns, one is hidden but it doesn't change anything to the problem.
I want to group on the value of the 3rd and hidden field, a date. When this Date is not present (null) I want to put the record in the "Actual Projects" group else they go in the "Closed projects" group.
It works BUT I want to have the group Actual Project first and I try a lot of thing with the sort direction of the field and the grid and also with `baseTitle` I return. It never change I always have the group with the non null value first.
Am I missing something? Is there somebody who experienced with group order?

```
   final int groupClosed = 2;
    final int groupActual = 1;


    colonneDate.setGroupValueFunction(new GroupValueFunction() {  
        public Object getGroupValue(Object value, ListGridRecord record, ListGridField field, String fieldName, ListGrid grid) {  
            Date laDate = (Date)value;            
            if(laDate == null) {  
                return groupActual;  
            } else {  
                return groupClosed;  
            }
        }  
    });  
    colonneDate.setGroupTitleRenderer(new GroupTitleRenderer() {

        @Override
        public String getGroupTitle(Object groupValue, GroupNode groupNode,
                ListGridField field, String fieldName, ListGrid grid) {
            final int groupType = (Integer) groupValue;
             String baseTitle ="";

            switch (groupType){
            case groupActual:
                 baseTitle ="Actual Projects";
                break;
            case groupClosed:
                  baseTitle ="Closed Projects";
                break;

            }           
            return baseTitle;
        }             
    });  


listeGridProjets.setGroupByField("date");
```

Comment: Try having a look at my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21468147/2662285

Comment: Sorry but I'm not working anymore on this project and don't have any access to the sources to try. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sort your ListGrid on your colonneDate like this :

```
SortSpecifier sortSpecifier = new SortSpecifier("colonneDateFieldName", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
SortSpecifier[] sortSpecifiers = { sortSpecifier };
setSort(sortSpecifiers);
```