# Smart GWT ListGrid Sorting after Grouping not working

Tags: smartgwt

I'm using a smart GWT list grid to display report data.

The ArrayList which is used for the data which populates the grid is sorted by the sequence number of the each object (Long value).

The data in the grid are grouped from one column.

Issue is data in the grid are not sorted from the sequence number when viewed through the system.

resultsGrid object is of type `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid`

```
resultsGrid.groupBy("location");
resultsGrid.setCanGroupBy(false);
```

I have tried to sort the values after groupBy with setting
  resultsGrid.sort(sortField, sortDirection);

For some records, the sequence is null and I want them to be displayed at the top

but it didn't work. What's the solution for this??

Comment: I tried the solutions given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217806/how-to-sort-records-with-code-in-a-grouped-listgrid. but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show, what code you have written till now?